# Strange Behavior With python FastAPI and transmission for a URL Encoded SHA1

Tags: python, fastapi, bittorrent

So I was trying to put together my own bittorent announce server in python, and iv run into a bit of a snag. For some reason I cant seem to get FastAPI to decode the URL Encoded SHA1 field of info_hash correctly.

As an example, I'm using the Ubuntu Torrent file, and receive a request like so:

```
GET /announce?info_hash=%99%c8%2b%b75%05%a3%c0%b4S%f9%fa%0e%88%1dnZ2%a0%c1
```

I get that its a URL Encoded SHA1 when I tried to dump it as a string:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/announce")
    async def announce(info_hash: str):
        print(info_hash) #prints: "��+�5���S���nZ2��"
```

So I tried to pull it as raw bytes, and then re-encode it.

```
@app.get("/announce")
    async def announce(info_hash: bytes):
        print(info_hash) #prints: b'\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd+\xef\xbf\xbd5\x05\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdS\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\x0e\xef\xbf\xbd\x1dnZ2\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

Which that byte array looks all sort of wrong to me. I don't get how 3 bytes: \xef\xbf\xbd become 9

Even looking at the Raw input to compare it, its not making a whole lot of sense.

```
SHA1 99 c8 2b b73505 a3 c0 b453f9 fa 0e 88 1d6e5a32a0c1
URL %99%c8%2b%b75%05%a3%c0%b4S%f9%fa%0e%88%1dnZ2%a0%c1
```

It looks like some of the bytes are encoded as ASCII? and anything outside of the ASCII range is encoded as a URL Encoded byte? IE: Hex(35) = 5

It looks like somehow under the hood, Fast API is decoding the characters directly, and Iv searched through the documentation and I cant figure out how to get it to stop

What is going on, and how do i Fix it?

Comment: How are you generating the encoded string? To me, it seems like that's what's wrong here.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using the hexadecimal SHA1 output, which should not need to be URL encoded at all.